# Shell Script error "No such file or directory ".

Tags: shell, unix

I have a simple Shell script as:

```
#!/bin/bash
/opt/ABC/bin/datastore.sh < /opt/data/table-db.ddl
```

Here I am trying to run ddl statements contained in table-db.ddl for datastore  DB.
The problem here is that for "/opt/data/table-db.ddl" ,it's giving error as "No such file or directorye 2: /opt/data/table-db.ddl".

The same line(/opt/ABC/bin/datastore.sh < /opt/data/table-db.ddl) when I execute from command line,it works.

Please let me know what the issue is here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: two options 1) you aren't executing the *same* thing. 2) (unlikely) some security programmer (apparmor, ...) running which prevents accessing certain files. check the error logs.

Comment: What is your current shell ? as i can see in your script, shell is bash.
that may be your shell issue.

Comment: Is your first line `#!/bin/bash` correct? No space or ^M (windows) at the end of the line? Do you have /bin/bash on your system?

Comment: What attempting to run a script, if you receive the error **No such file or directory** or **permission denied**, the general cause is most likely because **the script is not executable** (i.e. the execute bit isn't set for the `user`, `group` or `world` attempting to execute the file). Check with `ls` and then change the permission if necessary `chmod 0755 scriptname.sh`. A simple test if this is the issue is to run `bash scriptname.sh` and see if it works...

Comment: ls -l /opt/data/table-db.ddl gives me:
-rwxrwxrwx 1 agp agp 5447 Apr 20 22:02 /opt/data/table-db.ddl